# Como realizar este Select?

Tags: mysql, select

Eu preciso relacionar dados de acordo com o último item encontrado na tabela do usuário, por exemplo:

Tabela_A:

```
+----------------+-------------+
| user_id        | title_id    |
+----------------+-------------+
| 154138746      | 123         |
+----------------+-------------+
```

Tabela_B

```
+----------------+----------------------+
| title_id       | genres               |
+----------------+----------------------+
| 123            | Ação, Aventura, Drama|
+----------------+----------------------+
| 122            | Drama, Sci-fi        |
+----------------+----------------------+
| 126            | Romance, Aventura    |
+----------------+----------------------+
| 135            | Ação , Drama         |
+----------------+----------------------+
```

O que eu preciso é fazer um SELECT na tabela A recuperando os seus respectivos dados na tabela B, e então usando tais dados recuperar da mesma tabela B seus semelhantes com base na categoria, é possível fazer tudo em uma query ou é melhor dividir?

De preferência gostaria que a query retornasse somente os valores semalhantes encontrados na tabela_B, ignorando os outros que foram usandos somente como parâmetros para a pesquisa.

Estou tentando com a seguinte query:

```
SELECT  wt.user_id, wt.title_id, 
        fl.id, fl.genres, 
        sm.* 
            FROM watchedtitles wt 
            INNER JOIN filmes fl 
                ON wt.title_id = fl.id 

            LEFT JOIN filmes sm 
                ON FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fl.genres, ',', 1), fl.genres)
```

No caso watchedtitles é a minha tabela_A de onde pegarei o último item que o usuário assistiu e então procurar na tabela_B filmes, os seus semelhantes, porém ao usar o SUBSTRING_INDEX fico limitado a ter que todas as vezes digita index separado. Tendo em mente que a coluna genres é uma string contendo as categorias separadas por vírgula, como seria possível tal query?

Comment: Em vez dos tipos das colunas poderia colocar um exemplo de valor?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam adicionei alguns valores as tabelas

Comment: Tente com `REGEXP CONCAT('(', REPLACE(fl.genres, ', ', '|'), ')')`, isso deve criar uma regex do tipo `(Ação|Aventura|Drama)`, talvez tenha que fazer algumas adaptações

Comment: Poderia me fazer um exemplo de como seria tal adaptação?

Comment: Não consigo testar o sql agora, mas a ideia é transformar o valor da coluna `genres` em uma regex que possa ser usada para procurar filmes semelhantes, ficaria algo do tipo `LEFT JOIN filmes sm ON sm.genres REGEXP CONCAT('(', REPLACE(fl.genres, ', ', '|'), ')')`, mas como disse não posso testar pra ter certeza que vai funcionar

Comment: Parece funcionar bem, seria possível fazer um ORDER BY pelos resultados que contem mais categorias em comum?

Comment: Não consigo pensar em nenhuma forma simples de fazer isso, mas para contornar o problema você pode deixar o usuário definir suas categorias favoritas e ordenar por elas

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que usando a função `MySQL` chamada `FIND_IN_SET()` você possa conseguir o resultado, uma vez que ele vai buscar o gênero, na `tabela_c`, dentro de uma `string_list`, gêneros da `tabela_b`:

```
$sql="
    SELECT
        tabela_a.*,
        tabela_b.*,
        tabela_c.*
    FROM tabela_a
    INNER JOIN tabela_b
    ON tabela_a.title_id=tabela_b.title_id
    INNER JOIN tabela_c
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tabela_c.genres,tabela_b.genres)
";
```

> [Referência **FIND_IN_SET()**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp)

- OBS: Os `JOINS` e campos da tabela, `*`, você pode alterar de acordo com a sua necessidade, foi apenas exemplificado.